# Validate inlines before saving model

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys

Let's say I have these two models:

```
class Distribution(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)

class Component(models.Model):
    distribution = models.ForeignKey(Distribution)
    percentage = models.IntegerField()
```

And I'm using a simple `TabularInline` to show `Component`s inside the `Distribution` admin form:

```
class ComponentInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Component
    extra = 1

class DistributionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [ComponentInline]
```

So, my goal is to validate if the percentages of all the `Component`s of the `Distribution` sum 100 before saving it. Sounds simple, so I did:

```
# ... Inside the Distribution model
def clean(self):
    # Sum of components must be 100
    total_sum = sum(comp.percentage for comp in self.component_set.all())
    if total_sum != 100:
        raise ValidationError('Sum of components must be 100%')
```

But this will never work work, because in Django all objects are saved before saving its foreign-key or many2many related objects, this is not a flaw, it has a reason: it cannot save the related objects first, because the object to which they are related doesn't have an `id` defined yet (`id` is `None` until the object is saved for the first time in the DB).

I'm sure I'm not the first guy to run into this issue. So, is there a way to accomplish what I'm trying to do? I was thinking maybe a admin hack using `TabularInline` or `ModelAdmin` ... ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an (untested) idea, if you're happy to move the validation from the model to the inline formset:

Subclass `BaseInlineFormSet` and override the clean method to check the sum of the percentages.

```
from django.forms.models import BaseInlineFormSet
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

class ComponentInlineFormSet(BaseInlineFormSet):

    def clean(self):
        """Check that sum of components is 100%"""
        if any(self.errors):
            # Don't bother validating the formset unless each form is valid on its own
            return
        total_sum = sum(form.cleaned_data['percentage'] for form in self.forms)
        if total_sum != 100:
            raise ValidationError('Sum of components must be 100%')
```

Then use your inline formset in the `ComponentInline`.

```
class ComponentInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Component
    extra = 1
    formset = ComponentInlineFormSet
```

Comment: This is a nice idea! I knew the Inlines had a lot to offer. I'm going to try this right know

Comment: great! It worked nicely with a couple of changes. Thanks, really :)